# Twitter-Bootstrap Modal Bindinghandler with Knockout breaking if backdrop is clicked

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I'm trying to disable the backdrop from closing the modal when clicked with the following:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.showModal = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        if (ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value)) {
            $(element).modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: true });
            // this is to focus input field inside dialog
            $("input", element).focus();
        }
        else {

            $(element).modal('hide');
        }
    }
};
```

From what I understand, `$(element).modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: true });` should achieve what I'm after.  But if I click on the backdrop the modal still closes though, and in fact breaks the "show" button.  What am I doing wrong here?

Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/175/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is that you are trying to initialize your modal multiple times.

The initialization logic where you set `backdrop: 'static'` should go into the `init` function (which is called only once) and you need to call `.modal('show')` and `.modal('hide')` in your `update` function:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.showModal = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: true, show: false });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        if (ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value)) {
            $(element).modal('show');
            $("input", element).focus();
        }
        else { 
            $(element).modal('hide');
        }
    }
};
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vSnU7/).