# Knockout JS - How to return empty strings for observable fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

Im building a CRUD system where users can add, delete and edit data from a simple table. I have a modal form that is used to show additional details and also adding new incidents. Currently the modal form loads correctly for editing but has issues when trying to add a new incident.

After some debuging it seems that the issue comes from this line:

```
self.currentIncident(null);
```

This breaks my modal form because my observable is coming back null (obviously). I was hoping that it would return something like the following:

```
"ID": "",
"Description": "",
"Incident": ""
```

I believe this is why my modal is crashing since my modal is confused with the return. Would someone know of an easy method to return empty strings?

```
  self.AddNewIncident = function() {
    var id = this.ID;
    self.showModal(true);
    self.currentIncident(null);
  };
```

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rqwku4kb/12/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `{}` instead of `null` like this:

`self.currentIncident({});`

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/rqwku4kb/13/)

Comment: Sweet been litterly looking for this answer for days. It worked out great, thank you so much,

Comment: Sorry I needed to wait to accept your answer. THank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare *Incident* in this way:

```
function Incident(data) {
  var self = this;

  self.ID = -1;
  self.Description = ko.observable();
  self.Incident = ko.observable();

  if (!data) return;

  // initialize with 'data'
  self.ID = data.ID;
  self.Description(data.Description);
  self.Incident(data.Incident);
}
```

and then

```
    self.currentIncident(new Incident());
```